# response .sendRedirect not working

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have an application where i have to redirect  from a login page to another page the user name and the password i enter in the login page is going to another servlet.so from the servlet if i found the login values are matched i will redirect to another page,But this things are not working....I am posting my code

```
  boolean validationFlag = qb.userValidation(loginVO);
        if (validationFlag) {

            //This is for Ajax return 

            System.out.println("we are here");
            response.sendRedirect("../main.jsp");
            System.out.println("we are back");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here validationFlag is true and i have to redirect to anther page but it is not working

Comment: what is the problem you are getting? any stacktrace?

Answer (score 2):

You have to return afterwards. Otherwise, execution keeps going until the end of the JSP/servlet.

```
response.sendRedirect("../main.jsp");
return;
```

So without the return, your System.out.println("we are back"); will be executed.

Comment: boolean validationFlag = qb.userValidation(loginVO);
            if (validationFlag) {

                //This is for Ajax return 
//                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
//                response.getWriter().write("True");
                System.out.println("we are here");
                response.sendRedirect("../main.jsp");
                return;
            //    System.out.println("we are back");
                
            }

Answer (score 1):

First of all get clear with concept of when to use sendRedirect and when to use RequestDispatcher. (you are using 2 step process for simple validation)

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/05/difference-between-request-dispatcher.html
http://www.coderanch.com/t/540671/Servlets/java/difference-RequestDispatcher-sendRedirect

remove those println statements.
Remember you can't do sendRedirect() after writing to response object.

And now try,

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
```

here there is no problem of relative urls like the one you were using.

Hope this helps....happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try This, it may help :

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/main.jsp").forward(request, response);
```